# Adding dependencies for Osgi-projects in Gradle

Tags: java, osgi, gradle

I have a couple of osgi-projects that I would like to build using gradle.

When I try to build the "top"-project i.e. a project without required bundles it works just as I expect it to.

The problem is when I try to build a project that has multiple required bundles. I was hoping gradle would be so kind and just resolve it all for me, but it doesn't seem to work like that. Do I need to add all the required bundles/plug-ins to the dependencies/compile or is it some other issue?

I have googled like a maniac but I just can't find any useful information.

Has anyone been in a similar situation?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the problem is? Code example along with output would help.

Comment: Hi Peter! Well at the moment it's at a stage where it won't compile because it can't find the required classes. It compiles fine in my IDE but when I do a gradle build it gives me a ton of compilation errors.

Comment: Did you add the necessary dependencies? How is this different from a non-OSGi build?

Comment: Well that's my question, do I need to add them and how do I add them? It's pretty obvious it's missing the dependencies compile-time. Does my gradle.build-file need all the dependencies added?

Comment: Of course you'll need to add the dependencies. What else would you expect? Gradle user guide explains dependency management in detail (not in the context of OSGi, but I don't think it's relevant). You can also have a look at the samples contained in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Well somewhere deep down I hoped Gradle would to it for me, call me naive but there a A LOT of dependencies so I didn't want to face the truth so to speak :) I'll give it a new go! Thanks for the follow up and interest Peter!

Comment: Quick follow up question, where are the bundles that eclipse uses when I for example create a run config located? How can I reference them in my build.gradle-file?

Comment: @marko: did you have any progress researching this? We are doing the same thing as you, developing OSGI bundles with eclipse, and building them with jenkins using gradle. Currently we are managing dependencies by manually adding them in the build.gradle file. I would be interested in an exchange of experiences, my e-mail is on my user page.

Comment: @Ozan, what I ended up doing was figuring out where the bundles were put and I added it to my classpath. Now, that did it for me but your env is probably different. Not much help, but I hope it gets you forward. Otherwise, just drop me a line!